# How to create a report with logo touching header and detail

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm trying to create a report as shown below with a logo touching header and detail band... Can someone please help me on where to start with... Even the header end is having a cross lines... do i need to take that as an image or is it possible in ireport tool to have such designs??

I'm new to jasper reporting... Please help me on how to create such report

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about crossed lines since it's been a year since my last time using iReports, but I can't remember this kind of attention to the estetic part and I think you should probably use a background image.

Regarding the logo touching header and detail, since I don't think iReport can deal with overlapping bands, I would suggest you to organize your report as shown in the following image.

[image]

Header (red part): take care of the whole report non connected to the detail

Detail (green part): just your data

You can handle vertical lines in both bands in order to preserve a sort of frame.

I had to emulate several times this sample. and I've always reached my goal in this way.

Hoping it helps.

FF

Comment: Agree: background image works really good for "fixed height band" such as the header in this case

Comment: just as a small note its not a problem of iReport that is a IDE, but jasper report that is a library, hence switching IDE will not help ; )

Comment: Thanks panto for detailed explanation... How do i create a curved border to fit my logo in it??

Comment: as far as I remember, iReport provides lines, rectangles and ellipses... so I would suggest you to use a pre-framed image in order to achive your needs... I know it's not a solution but it's how I would do

Comment: @pathfinder: does the answer need more help or are you done? ;)

Comment: preframed image means?? Do we need to prepare image in that way??

Comment: yes i meant that: your type of border is something that, imho, is above iReport capabilities... so I'd suggest you to create a logo with a frame around it BEFORE adding it as an image in iReport

Comment: In that case how would i cover the blue borders on left and right side of the image??

Comment: Created two frames before and after image and was able to make it work.... Thanks Fabio Fantoni!!!